# Create a script to subscribe a MQTT topics

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to create a script that opens a terminal with 3 tabs to subsribe MQTT topics to be monitored. This script will be loaded during boot.

Such script in ubuntu is shown below but raspbian does not use `gnome-terminal`- so I'm looking for fitted syntax for Raspberry-pi Terminal:

```
#! /bin/bash

sub1="myHome/Messages"
sub2="myHome/log"
sub3="myHome/debug"
user="guy"
pass="12345678"
mqtt_broker="192.168.2.100"

gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub1 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub1
gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub2 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub2
gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub3 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub3

gnome-terminal -- mosquitto_pub -u $user  -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t "myHome/All" -m "status"
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a python program or locally written C/C++ program to subscribe to the three topics or do it with a single `myHome/#` (anything that starts with `myHome`) or `myHome/+` (anything with a single level behind `myHome`) subscription that covers all three topics. When a message arrives you can read `message.topic` to find whether it's `myHome/Messages`, `myHome/log` or `myHome/debug`. That's got to be easier than trying to open three windows each subscribed to a differing topic.

Answer (score 1):

RpiOS uses a modified version of [LXDE](http://www.lxde.org/) as its default desktop environment;
it provides `lxterminal`.  It probably does not have some of the command line features of gnome-terminal; have a look at `man lxterminal`. If you are having trouble getting it to do what you want, you are better off asking about that on our bigger sibling site
[Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) (and/or try the forums on that LXDE site, they are accessible through the menu icon top right on the front page).

If necessary, it should not be impossible to install gnome-terminal and run it in LXDE, but this is not very desirable as it likely links to a stack of gnome libraries that aren't otherwise in use and largely duplicate functionality in LXDE, meaning it may eat a good chunk of RAM when in use.

Comment: not installing gnome-terminal, was from that exact reason